# Problem using Pythonnet (Python for .Net) in Visual Studio

Tags: python, vb.net, python.net

I am trying a very simple project with Pythonnet (Python for .NET) in order to try to solve more complex problems using Python modules in a code written in VB.NET.

So far I have installed Pythonnet via `pip install` and am trying a first .vb code without a .py yet.

I am using Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019, Python 3.7.6. I have added to the project in VStudio the reference to `Python.Runtime`, which I copied to `\Python\Python37\DLLs`.

I have tried the following code:

```vb
Imports System
Imports Python.Runtime

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        PythonEngine.Initialize()
        Using (Py.GIL())
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")
        End Using
    End Sub
End Module
```

And got the following error:

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder System.AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess)'.'
```

Comment: Is that the entire error message?

Comment: Were you able to fix this?